# iphone maps GPS icon

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to make a button that centers the map on the current GPS location. Google Maps app has that icon on bottom left. Where can I get that icon. Is it embedded in the SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That button image is not publicly available for use in the SDK.  This question was asked recently on SO but I am unable to find the original question, perhaps someone else will be able to dig it up.  This free icon set (http://glyphish.com/) has one that is pretty close.

Comment: Thanks, that set has the icon I was looking for and more.