# Iphone google map GPS Icon

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, icons

I would like to create an button like the one in maps.app, which can center the map on the current GPS location. I find the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626623/iphone-maps-gps-icon). After I setting the GPS icon image as the image of GPS button, there is apparent sawtooth on the edges of the icon. Is there any other approach to get a good looking GPS icon? Thanks in advance!

[image: GPS Icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should try to read the ios document below first:
[The Retina display allows you to display high-resolution versions of your art and icons. If you merely scale up your existing artwork, you miss out on the opportunity to provide the beautiful, captivating images users expect.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1)

1. Scale up your original artwork to 200%
2. Add detail and depth.
3. Consider softening scaled-up elements.
4. Consider adding blur for better results in effects such as engravings and drop shadows.

---

if you want an image named 30x30.png with a size of 30x30px, then you should create an image named 30x30@2x.png with a size of 60x60px.   [this is a same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854999/make-a-fine-tabbar-icon)