# Make a fine tabBar icon

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, uitabbarcontroller

As we know the default icon size for the tabBar is 30x30 point. I have an icon with thin lines and the display property is not that good. Its edge is not sharp. But I find the tabBar icon of music.app is really pretty with sharp edge. Is there any trick I should know? Thanks in advance!

[image: music.app tabBar icon]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's 30x30 points, which could be either 30x30 pixels, or 60x60 pixels, depending if the device has a retina display or not. That image looks to be displayed on a retina device.

If you have an image, for example, named MusicTabIcon.png, have two versions...

1. One @ 30x30 pixels named MusicTabIcon.png
2. One @ 60x60 pixels named MusicTabIcon@2x.png